# Setting Up a New SSL Project on MAMP Pro

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, ssl, mamp-pro

I just purchased MAMP Pro as I have moved most of my websites over to SSL.

I cannot for the life of me, get the assets or files to load. So essentially any of the CSS/JS/IMAGES. The website itself loads with plain text, but that is it.

The error message I'm getting in the dev tools for all the assets not loading is: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

---

Here is what I've tried:

1. Set my self-signed certificates to ALWAYS TRUST [(tip from from this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838052/use-ssl-with-mamp-pro-4)
2. Reset my browser history + cache
3. I tried different browsers and incognito mode, and they all show the same issue

---

I also do not have an ad blocker installed, as some other posts I have read indicated that was their problem.

The lock, however, is appearing in the address bar, so the certificate appears to be working, but still causing the assets to be blocked on load.

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** I fixed it. Because I was using MAMP before MAMP Pro, my old projects had the database linking to localhost:8888. I had to go in and revise the WordPress tables to my updated siteurl home. Hope this helps someone!